# Add new icon for the push notification in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I use the `phonegap-plugin-push` plugin in mine Phonegap app, and I want to set a different icon instead of the used logo app, for the push notification.
Following the documentations I do it with this code; anyway this not work, it always use the app icon instead of the new one that I want.

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    "android": {
        "senderID": "xxx",
        "icon": "ic_stat_icon"
    }
});
```

I put my `ic_stat_icon.png` image in the `platform/android/res` folder

Answer (score 1):

I've spent the whole afternoon on this problem - done everything that it says in the Push Plugin documentation and more - and it appears that putting an extra tag in your Android manifest fixes the problem:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/icontrans" />
```

... where icontrans is the name of my icon.

For reference, I also put the icons into each of the res/drawable folders using the following in my config.xml:

```
    <resource-file src="res/icon/icon-18-trans.png" target="res/drawable-ldpi/icontrans.png" />
    <resource-file src="res/icon/icon-24-trans.png" target="res/drawable-mdpi/icontrans.png" />
    <resource-file src="res/icon/icon-36-trans.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/icontrans.png" />
    <resource-file src="res/icon/icon-48-trans.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/icontrans.png" />
    <resource-file src="res/icon/icon-72-trans.png" target="res/drawable-xxhdpi/icontrans.png" />
    <resource-file src="res/icon/icon-96-trans.png" target="res/drawable-xxxhdpi/icontrans.png" />
```

Not sure if it's something to do with the later platforms (I'm targeting SDK 26) or the fact I'm using Firebase to send the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your image in `platform/android/res/drawable`.

I don't know if it's necessary but you can try also put your images in the others drawables folders (drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc).

Comment: Thank you, but I've already tried to do it, without solve the problem @shino47